# Backtracking in matrix to get min element

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics, backtracking

[Not sure if I should post here, if not let me know please!]

The problem lies in the backtracking procedure of the [method of Zucker's](http://ab.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/teaching/ws06/albi1/script/rna_structure_06Dec2006.pdf) for minimizing energy in a secondary RNA structure, which uses dynamic programming.

So, I have the upper triangular matrix `W`, who is filled with this formula:

```
W(i, j) = min([W(i,j-1),
               W(i+1,j),
               V(i,j),
               min_k   // I will use an example, where this argument is NOT used
             ]);
```

At the same time I also fill a backtrack table `B` with this logic:

```
if(min was the first option)
  B(i, j) = 10;
elseif(min was the 2nd option)
  B(i, j) = 11;
elseif(min was the 3rd option)
  B(i, j) = 12;
else
  // doesn't matter now
```

I am not sure if I have to show how `V` is filled.

I *am sure that these matrices are created corrected*.

The problem is that I have to show all the backtrack paths leading to the minimum value of `W`.

Note that this question is not about *give me the code*. It is to get the big picture of how backtracking should be performed with a single example. Pseudo-code should also do the trick I guess.

Example:

```
x = CACGGUUAG // input
W =

      Inf      Inf      Inf        8        8        8        5        5        5
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf        8        8        5        5        5
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf        8        8        8        6
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf        8        8        8
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf        8        8
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf        8
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf
      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf      Inf

B =
         C        A        C        G        G        U        U        A        G
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     C   0        0        0       12       10       10       11       10       10
     A   0        0        0        0       12       10       12       10       10
     C   0        0        0        0        0       12       10       10       12
     G   0        0        0        0        0        0       12       10       10
     G   0        0        0        0        0        0        0       12       10
     U   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       12
     U   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
     A   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
     G   0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

From what I can understand, because I couldn't find information on how to proceed after filling the matrices, so I improvised.

I only *know* that backtrack starts from top right corner.
So, I said:

```
if(B(i, j) == 10)
  go left
elseif(B(i, j) == 11)
  go down
else
  go left and down
```

which in this example yields

```
<-   GC  // left
<-   AC
|
v    UA  // down
 /
V    UC  // left and down
 /
v    UG
```

which seems to work, since, if you take the path from UG in array `W`, you will find yourself in the right top corner of `W` which I think has what we are looking for.

The problem with this logic I made up, is how to get all optimal paths and not just the one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the backtrack table so that it indicates the existence of multiple minima. You could have codes like this:

1. first option minimum
2. second option minimum
3. first and second options tied for minimum
4. third option minimum
5. first and third options tied for minimum
6. second and third options tied for minimum
7. first, second, and third options tied for minimum

Then change the backtracking to be nondeterministic. If you're in a typical imperative programming language, the usual way to do this is to make a recursive function that returns all possible tracks from a given matrix cell. Then you have recursion in a loop like so.

```
def backtrack(predecessors, cell):
    possibilities = []
    if cell == (0, 0);
        possibilities.append([cell])
    else:
        for predecessor in predecessors[cell]:
            for rest in backtrack(predecessors, predecessor):
                possibilities.append([cell] + rest)
    return possibilities
```

Comment: Based on my approach on the question, there is no hope? I do not really want to change the approach. Notice that even I can find them manually (the optimal paths), I would still be happy and then, once I understand the logic and I can expand to your more precise approach.

Comment: @G.Samaras You can use the `W` table to look up entries of the revised `B` on the fly.

Comment: Yes this is what I am thinking, can you please explain how? :) I am struggling here..

Comment: @G.Samaras At `(i,j)`, if `W(i,j) == W(i,j-1)`, then backtracking to `(i,j-1)` is an option. If `W(i,j) == V(i,j)`, then stopping at `(i,j)` is an option.

Comment: Can you confirm? Assuming that you also meant about `i+1`. 1) Path:  W(1, 9) -> W(1, 8) -> W(1, 7)  
   x_opt: GAU
   y_opt: CCC
     
2) Path:  W(1, 9) -> W(1, 8) -> W(2, 8) -> W(2, 7)
   x_opt: GAAU
   y_opt: CCAA
       
3) Path:  W(1, 9) -> W(2 ,9) -> W(2, 8) -> W(2, 7)
   x_opt: GGAU
   y_opt: CAAA

Comment: @G.Samaras Shouldn't the first one go to (2, 7) as well?

Comment: at (2,7) at the 1st, V(2,7) == W(2,7)
which u didn't know
so based on "If W(i,j) == V(i,j), then stopping at (i,j) is an option."
it should not, right? :)

Comment: Well actually you could see that from the example I have in my question. I hope I am correct. If I am, then there is no need for more and I will accept and up-vote your answer.

Comment: I am going to accept the answer, but I will wait for your confirmation comment in order to up-vote. :)